# PHP not doing simple echo

Tags: php, mamp

I am trying to test my php file called `home.php` in firefox. I have put the file in htdocs, changed the port settings from default and 80/3306 but no luck. The link I am typing in is `localhost/home.php` and not working.

The home.php code.

```
<?php
<p> echo "Hello World"; </p>
?>
```

What could be the problem ?

It is saying 'firefox cannot establish a connection to the server at localhost'.

I just restarted the MAMP servers and now it is saying 'Not Found. The requested URL /home.php was not found on this server. '

Comment: You should put the `<p>` inside the echo statement:  `echo "<p>Hello World</p>";`

Comment: @developerCK: pointing someone to w3fools to learn php is like telling a novice they can check if their gun is loaded by pointing it at their head and pulling the trigger.

Comment: @MarcB, You are right!

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing HTML and PHP in a way that causes syntax errors. Try keeping them separate, like this:

```
<p><?php echo "Hello World"; ?></p>
```

You should usually avoid embedding HTML tags in your PHP output when possible. However, if you need your tags to be dynamic, you can place them in the output string:

```
<?php echo "<p>Hello World</p>"; ?>
```

In response to the newly-added error ("firefox cannot establish a connection to the server at localhost") please verify that you have a web server installed and that it is running at the specified port (80 by default).

Comment: Yes, Apache is running at 80 and mySql is 3306.

Comment: @jazza96 If you have confirmed that Apache is running and can respond to requests, there are at least three other possibilities: The vhost is configured incorrectly, Firefox is connecting to the wrong host, or a firewall rule is blocking access. For help with those issues, consider asking your question on Serverfault.

Comment: Also, you may want to try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.  Not a likely fix, but if the config files are messed up somehow...

Answer (score -1):

`<p>`is a html tag this is not define in PHP. Your code is giving error because `<P>` is unknown for php. PHP engine not able to compile this html tag 
you need to care about PHP right syntax

Comment: BINGO! The first one worked. Maybe I should take developerCK's advice and go to W3schools. Thanks